# c# Unique Collection Replacing Equal Items Based on Second Property

Tags: c#

I want to maintain a large unique collection of a certian object. The objects are compared by value-by-value comparison of an integer array, and if that is equal, i want to keep the one with highest value of another integer property.

At the moment I'm using a class which has a dictionary, dictionary<string,myObject> whose key is a string representation of the objects integer array, ie. string.join(",", array), and if i add an object and the list already contains one with identical matching string key, it will replace the object in question if object A.PropertyB > object B.PropertyB. This works fine but I have a large data set and it is slow, mainly because of the string.join(..) bit. I was hoping there might be a better way of achieving this?

This is my add function:

```
       private readonly Dictionary<string, myObject> myHashLookup = new Dictionary<(string,int), myObject>();

       public void Add(myObject t)
        {
            string id = t.GetId(); // string.join(",", myIntArray)
        myObect cur_object;
            myHashLookup.TryGetValue(id, out cur_object);            
            if ( cur_object == null || (t.PropertyB > cur_object.PropertyB))
                myHashLookup[id)] = t;            
        }
```

Comment: Do something like this :  Dictionary<string, myObject> dict = input.OrderByDescending(x => t.PropertyB).GroupBy(x => x.id).Select(x => x.First()).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.First());

Comment: yeah i started using that approach to remove duplicates after every 10k adds, but as the number gets larger it gets impossibily slow, so i wrote the custom list class which is quicker but still too slow.

Comment: The second condition `|| (t.PropertyB > cur_object.PropertyB)` will always be false. You search the dictionary for the key tuple (id, PropertyB). If that is found PropertyB of t will always be equal to the PropertyB of cur_object. Am I missing something?

Comment: @CristianRusanu : The dictionary is the output of the search.  The input is a list with duplicates.  Check you memory in Task Manager.  You probably are running low on memory.   Your code should run the same as mine.  The only difference is the hash method or a memory issue.

Comment: @CristianRusanu thanks yeah I was trying to rename my properties to simplify it but made a mistake there, ive corrected it now

Comment: @jdweng the problem is that maybe 80% of the items trying to add to the list are duplicated. at about 100m items and 50gb memory usage it gets really slow, so i tried removing the duplicates every 10k with a groupby like you suggested but it's still too slow, so I switched to the custom list and check each time approach i put here but it is still too slow.

Comment: You can order by ID and then search for highest PropertyB.  The ids will be grouped but in theory the run time should be the same.  Something else is going on if your code is running fastest than mine.  Class objects are suppose to get linked (not duplicated) so memory when you create a dictionary only the hash keys and link take up additional memory.